# Recommendations for multiletter subscripts in an equation

Tags: equations, subscripts

Are there recommendations for multiletter subscripts in equations?

I need to use `fr` for "friction" and the plain old `_{fr}` doesn't look very good.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\omega_{fr}$ vs.
$\omega_{\rm fr}$ vs.
$\omega_{f\!r}$ vs.
$\omega_{\!f\!r}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

For something like a full word I would use `{\rm foo}` or `\operatorname{foo}` or `\max`; not sure about 2 letters.

Comment: `_{\mathrm{fr}}`

Comment: why `\mathrm` instead of `\rm`?

Comment: Because `\rm` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: ... odd... how does one find this out? I don't see any warning in the output.

Comment: Try with the `memoir` class and you'll get a full-fledged error instead. The standard classes still define `\rm` and the other two-letter font selection commands for back compatibility, but classes are not required to.

Comment: "how does one find this out? " that is the wrong question. You should ask how  you found out about `\rm` which is not ever mentioned in the latex book or other official documention,

Comment: "You should ask how you found out about \rm" -- I have no idea, probably found some  sample TeX content online. Clearly I have touched a nerve, and now I am educated. I think if this is important to root out of the collective consciousness, you and egreg are doing the right thing by emphasizing it here. (But if it is supposed to be deprecated, MiKTeX and other environments ought to produce warnings that say this.)

Comment: At any rate, the `\rm` deprecation is an issue that is orthogonal to the one I raised in this question.

Comment: I'm going to try asking on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635207

Comment: @JasonS, the comments are fine, but things start to become hard to follow. Can you please sum its essence up and add to your question? Might make things easier to follow in (near) future and to provide better solutions. Thanks